# how to eliminate a trace of GRUB that stops me from opening Win10

Tags: boot

I have a hard drive that has data on it I want. It came from a failed PC that had Win10 on one drive and Ubuntu on another. The Ubuntu drive failed and was disconnected. Months later the old PC failed and I can't open the Win10 HDD with my new PC.

When I try to boot from the HDD I get a black screen with:

**error: no such device: b3eabeb5-992f-49e1-88c0-56be090c790a.

Entering rescue mode>

grub rescue>**

When I hit ENTER I get another grub rescue>. I think, even though Ubuntu is not on the HDD, that a trace of grub is. I might be able to fix it by installing Ubuntu in my new PC and then uninstalling it, hoping the uninstall would remove that trace of grub, but I am reluctant to risk screwing up my new C:/ drive.

Does anyone have any idea for removing stray bits of Grub so I can boot up my old HDD?

John

Comment: Grub has nothing to do with with you being able to boot from "my old HDD". If it's bootable, just select the correct boot order in the BIOS, and if not, you'll need to get a Windows recovery DVD/USB, and restore its bootloader. Obviously, reinstalling and then removing Ubuntu will do nothing to that end. There are many similar questions here, so do try searching. https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on

Answer (score 1):

Since you just want data off the old disk, boot an Ubuntu USB (or CDROM), and copy what you want off the hard disk to another USB storage device.  Even if you set up grub on the old disk, (easy to just install grub to it if you have some room on a FAT partition like the tools partition of Windows), actually running Windows with all the old drivers is unlikely to succeed.